# How to highlight full text by given word using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying highlight some word when user type anything. But the main problem is I am using  onChange event, so when user type anything I only get the current value as a result I am unable to highlight full word once user finish typing. here is my code below

search result is coming from backend

```
  const handleOnChange = async (e) => {
    setSearchText(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value.length <= 0) {
      setSearchSuggestion(true);
    } else {
      setSearchSuggestion(false);
      await search(e.target.value, setRows);
      handleSearchHighliter(e.target.value);
    }
  };
```

code highlighting code

```
  const handleSearchHighliter = (str) => {
    //styles.match_text
    let classArray = [...document.querySelectorAll("#search")];
    for (let arr of classArray) {
      //console.log(arr?.innerText);
      let innerHTML = arr.innerHTML;
      let index = innerHTML.indexOf(str);

      //console.log(innerHTML);

      if (index >= 0) {
        arr.innerHTML = innerHTML.replace(
          str,
          `<b style='background-color: yellow'>${str}</b>`,
        );
        //arr.innerHTML;
        //console.log(innerHTML);
      } else {
        continue;
      }
    }
  };
```

[image]

I need to highlight full Teamwork word

Comment: You mean when the user removes focus from the input the full word doesn't get highlighted?

Comment: Like we have 10 search results, If I type full word only the last word gets highlight rest of the line only highlights the previously typed word.